# Firebase security child node

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I have this DB structure in Firebase:

```
    [bets]
      -KTd9VKWJwHd_L6j_oAF
        date
        team1
        etc
      -KTdCc7uVmueNtcYzU1m
        date
        team1
        etc
   [users]
```

I'm now trying to write Firebase rules to allow users to only read bets assigned to them. But I ran into problems right away. I have these very basic rules:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "bets": {
      "$bet": {
        ".read": true,
        ".write": true
      }
    }
  }
}
```

When I try to visit `/bets` (where I display a list of bets) I get thrown the error:

```
Error: permission_denied at /bets: Client doesn't have permission to access the desired data.
```

If I instead place the `.read` and `.write` under `bets` instead of `$bet`, it works fine. What am I missing?

Answer (score 3):

Firebase evaluates read permission at the location where you attach a listener. You attach a listener to `/bets`, so it rejects the listener since you don't have read permission on `/bets`.

If you have read permission to `/bets`, you also can read everything under it. So this means that you can't use Firebase Database security rules to filter data.

See the section [rules are not filters](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/securing-data#rules_are_not_filters) in the Firebase documentation. Or search for [Firebase questions mentioning "rules are not filters"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bfirebase%5D+rules+are+not+filters) here and you'll see this is a common pitfall for developers.